# Avoid link visit if html element has class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magnific-popup

I have a HTML -Element as a purchase link for an article. When this article is soldout this link gets the class="sold-out". When someone clicks the link it will open a jQuery maginific-popup which contains the checkout form. But when it has the class "sold-out" I want, that this link isn't clickable. And to realize this link-follow prevention I have problems.

**My HTML:**

```
<a href="checkout.php" class="btn-1 ajax-popup sold-out">Purchase</a>
```

**My JS:**

```
$('.ajax-popup').mousedown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass("sold-out")) {
        return false;
    }
    var region = $(this).data('region');
    var quantity = $(this).data('quantity');
    if(typeof quantity == 'undefined') quantity = $(this).parent().find('select').val();
    var packageid = $(this).data('packageid');

    $(this).magnificPopup({
      type: 'ajax',
      ajax: {
          settings: {
              data : {
                  region : region,
                  quantity : quantity,
                  packageid : packageid,
              }
          }
      },
      closeOnContentClick: false,
      closeOnBgClick: false
   });

});
```

**What happens:**
In fact its avoiding the ajax-popup but in this case it's still following the link of the HTML-element but it shoudln't do anything. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to also add `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent the click from firing.

You are just listening for the `mousedown` event but a `click` event is also fired on the element as well, and by default the `click` event for a `<a>` tag will follow the `href` attribute.

I'm curious why you are binding to the `mousedown` event and not the `click` event?  If you change to the `click` event, the `e.preventDefault()` would handle this directly I believe.

Comment: adding stopPropogation after preventDefault hasn't worked for me, but changing mousedown to click worked for me. Thank you for the explanation. I will keep this in mind :). I can accept this answer in 8 minutes - you've been to fast :P

Comment: `stopPropagation` will work.  I think you have a typo in how you spelled `Propogation`, but yes, using `click()` is better.